# Keep order of SGPlot group colors

Tags: plot, sas

I would like to keep the order of the colors shown in an sgplot bar chart. I don't care which colors are used, I only would like to maintain the order of the colors.

In the example below plant 1 is blue in the first graph and red in the second. How can I make sure that the plants get the same colors?

I was hoping the grouporder option would help, but obviously it doesn't. I would like to avoid changing the "attrs" and take advantage of the "reasonable defaults".

```
Data A;
  Input Scenario $ Product $ Plant $ Quantity;
  Datalines;
XX A 1 100
XX B 1 200
XX C 1 300
XX A 2 333
XX D 2 888
YY F 1 100
YY B 1 200
YY C 1 300
YY A 2 333
YY D 2 888
;;;

Proc SGPlot Data=A (Where=(Scenario = 'XX')) ;
  VBar Product / Response=Quantity Stat=Sum Group=Plant 
               Dataskin=Sheen Transparency=0.4 
               GroupOrder=Ascending;
Run;

Proc SGPlot Data=A (Where=(Scenario = 'YY')) ;
  VBar Product / Response=Quantity Stat=Sum Group=Plant 
               Dataskin=Sheen Transparency=0.4 
               GroupOrder=Ascending;
Run;
```

Which gives:
[image]

and:
[image]

Comment: You need to use a data attribute map. Basically create a dataset that assigns a colour to each group and pass it to SGPLOT. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/30/auto-discrete-attr-map.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did this (which seems overly complex, I am still interested in better answers than my own, colors are different but consistent):

```
Data A;
  Input Scenario $ Product $ Plant $ Quantity;
  Datalines;
XX A 1 100
XX B 1 200
XX C 1 300
XX A 2 333
XX D 2 888
YY F 1 100
YY B 1 200
YY C 1 300
YY A 2 333
YY D 2 888
;;;

* Could not find SAS-standard;
Data MyColorList;
  Length FillColor $7.;
  Input FillColor $ @@;
  Nr = _N_;
  Datalines;
#00FF00 #00FFFF #70DB93 #D9D919  
#A67D3D #FF7F00 #855E42 #545454  
#238E23 #4E2F2F #8E236B #DB70DB  
#8C1717 #DB9370 #D8D8BF
;;;

%Let VarName = Plant;
Proc SQL;
  Create Table DAttrs As Select Distinct &VarName. As Value From A Order By     &VarName.;
Quit;

Data DAttrs (Drop=rc Nr);
  If _N_ eq 1 Then Do;
    Declare Hash H (Dataset: "MyColorList");
    H.Definekey('Nr');
    H.Definedata('FillColor');
    H.Definedone();
    If 0 Then Set MyColorList;
  End;
  Set DAttrs;
  ID = "&VarName.";
  Nr = mod(_N_, 15);
  rc = H.Find();
Run;

Proc SGPlot Data=A (Where=(Scenario = 'XX')) 
            DAttrMap=DAttrs ;
  VBar Product / Response=Quantity Stat=Sum 
                 Group=&VarName. AttrID=&VarName. 
             GroupOrder=ascending Dataskin=Sheen 
                 Transparency=0.4 NoStatLabel ;
Run;

Proc SGPlot Data=A (Where=(Scenario = 'YY')) 
            DAttrMap=DAttrs ;
  VBar Product / Response=Quantity Stat=Sum 
             Group=&VarName. AttrID=&VarName. 
             GroupOrder=ascending Dataskin=Sheen 
                 Transparency=0.4 NoStatLabel;
Run;
```

Which leads to this:
[image]

And:

[image]